# Codeception, gherkin test, how organize my code?

Tags: php, codeception

I followed the official Codeception guide (from their website of course) and I created a simple test written in Gherkin.

With the command `codecept gherkin:snippets` command, I printed all methods I must implement. Then I copied these methods to the `tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php` file.

My question is: today, it's a sample test, but tomorrow, if I must create a lot of acceptance tests, how do I organize my code ?

I suppose I must write each main scenario in several PHP files. But, where I can save these files? How do I link these files together?

Let's say I must create two big scenarios of acceptance tests. The `Scenario A` can be run alone, but the `Scenario B` must be run after the `Scenario A`.

Where do I need to create the files A and B? And, how can I "say" to Codeception I can run the `Scenario B` only after the `A` has been executed?

Sorry for my English, I hope my questions are clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeception, write acceptance tests with the pageObject design pattern and gherkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132683/codeception-write-acceptance-tests-with-the-pageobject-design-pattern-and-gherk)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Codeception that a scenario depends on something else by using `@depends` followed by the test signature. [According to the documentation](https://codeception.com/docs/07-BDD):

> And what is more interesting, you can make tests to depend on feature
>   scenarios. Let’s say we have `login.feature` file with “Log regular
>   user” scenario in it. In this case you can specify that every test
>   which requires login to pass to depend on “Log regular user” scenario:
>
> `@depends login:Log regular user`
>
> Inside `@depends` block you should use test signature. Execute your
>   feature with `dry-run` to see signatures for all scenarios in it. By
>   marking tests with `@depends` you ensure that this test won’t be
>   executed before the test it depends on.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, I created a new post with a full exemple of pageObject/stepObject/Gherkin here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132683/codeception-write-acceptance-tests-with-the-pageobject-design-pattern-and-gherk). I close this post.